# Help me figure out what sets these minifigs belong to!

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I was given a huge box of LEGO bricks from my neighbor and these are the last men I can't figure out what sets they come from.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Numbering your minifigures 1 to 19 by going from left to right, top row first, I see the following:

1. [gen035 - Skeleton with Round Brick Head (Ninjago Bowling Pin)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=gen035#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from set [2519 Skeleton Bowling](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2519-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).
   [image]
2. Same as 1
3. Same as 1
4. [oct027 - Octan - Racing, Blue Legs, Blue Helmet 4 Stars & Strips, Trans-Light Blue Visor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=oct027#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from set [9293 Community Workers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9293-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D). Note that the minifig head in this figure is not correct in your image - it was likely swapped out by the previous owner.
   [image]
5. The torso is [973pb0510 - Torso SW Armor Clone Trooper Pattern (Clone Wars)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0510#T=C). There are several minifigs that have this torso, including 8 with white arms and black hands. A full list is located here: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0510&in=M
6. Not LEGO.
7. Not LEGO.
8. Torso is [973px83 Torso SW Dark Gray Shirt, Belt with Red Buckle Pattern (Padme)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973px83&in=M), which belongs to [sw025 Padme Naberrie](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw025#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from one of two sets from 1999: [7131 - Anakin's Podracer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7131-1) or [7171 - Mos Espa Podrace](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7171-1). Note that the arms must have been swapped out by the previous owner as the original minifig had blue arms. 
   [image][image][image]
9. Either [njo007 Kai](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo007#T=S&O=%7B%7D) (missing his headscarf) or [njo052 Kendo Kai](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo052#T=S&O=%7B%7D) (missing his Kendo gear). Appear in 7 sets from 2011/2012.
10. [sw258 - Hoth Officer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw258&name=Hoth%20Officer&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%204/5/6%5D#T=S&O=%7B%7D) (with another minifig's head on top). From set [8083 Rebel Trooper Battle Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8083-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).
    [image]
11. [cc4066 Actor 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cc4066#T=S&O=%7B%7D). From polybag [4066 - Actor 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4066-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D), released in 2001.
    [image][image]
12. [njo013 - Lord Garmadon (Ninjago)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo013#T=S&O=%7B%7D). Could also be one of 2 other Lord Garmadon minifigs (with different gear). Part of [several Ninjago sets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo013#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from 2011.
13. Not LEGO.
14. Not LEGO.
15. Not LEGO
16. [sw401 Imperial AT-ST Driver](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw401#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from set [9679 - AT-ST & Endor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9679-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).
    [image]
17. The torso is [973pb0318c01 Torso Speed Racer Pullover Open Collar, Diagonal Wrinkles Pattern / Blue Arms / Light Flesh Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0318c01&in=M) from the Speed Racers theme. The legs do not belong to this torso. Torso belongs to [sr001 Speed Racer, Blue Pullover](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sr001#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from set [8158 - Speed Racer & Snake Oiler](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8158-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from 2008.
    [image][image]
18. Another likely Castle related torso that I haven't been able to identify yet. Seems to have a sticker on it.
19. Thanks to Samuel L.(!), this torso is [973px67c01 Torso Police Vest, White Shirt, ID, Yellow Star Badge Pattern / White Arms / Yellow Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973px67c01#T=C&C=11). It was part of [11 minifigures](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973px67c01&in=M) in the Classic Town theme, and those minifigures appeared in [18 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973px67c01&in=S).

Comment: I think the last one might be from the Lego system police series. http://img.bricklink.com/ItemImage/MN/0/soc045.png. To check out the entire system police series:https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Town/instructions2/subtheme-Police. I'm not quite sure which set it came from, as it came in a lot of these system police sets.

Comment: Thanks! Added that to my answer. Curious why this torso didn't show up in my search - it seems to have most items that I searched for listed in the name.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will spend the next while trying to make the sets to see if I've received all of the pieces....